# PHP Upload and process a CSV file

Tags: php, file, csv

I have an upload form which takes a csv file. Then I process it with PHP.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ladda upp!" class="upload_sub"/>

    <br />
    <br />

</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if($_FILES["csv"]["error"] > 0) {

        echo 'Ett fel inträffade vid uppladdning av filen. Var god försök igen.';

    } else {

        $tmp = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];

        $import = new Importer();
        $import->importTariff($tmp);


    }

}

?>
```

**lib.php class Importer** ( I only submit the relevant function )

```
public function importTariff($tmp) {

    if(($handle = fopen($tmp, 'r')) !== FALSE) {

         while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE) {

            echo 'foo';

         }

    }

}
```

For testing purposes I would like to print 'foo' for each line in the csv. However I get no errors or anything like it so any ideas?

Comment: I've noticed that $tmp is null. How do I work with the $_FILE variable?

Comment: Change name of fileinput from 'file' to 'csv'

Answer (score 2):

```
 print_r($_FILES);
```

Check out your **NAME** from file-input:

```
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
```

Rename it to `name="csv"` or change `$_FILES["csv"]` to `$_FILES["file"]`

Comment: Yep, that is correct. My bad. However a new issue has occured.

http://codepad.org/Yvgu5GuR

It only seem to write ONE row to the database then the script stops.

Comment: Can you post the content of the CSV?

Comment: Remove the length (`1000`) or set it to `0` for testing.

Comment: Here is the CSV content. It's a tariff for phone bills
http://codepad.org/KHu3y9gu

Comment: Okay, looks valid but i think a CSV-Header is missing (Standard: the first line).

Comment: Before you add these to the database, debug it. Comment out the `importTariffSQL` method and add only an `var_dump($data);` to check the loop

Comment: I have already made sure the $query is valid by echo'ing it out in the importTariffSQL function.

Comment: And the Data itself? What good is it if the query is valid, but the loop does not read the lines?

Comment: It does read the csv correctly. The $query looks good at each run, however it only write the FIRST line to the database.

Comment: Works for me. Can you tell me what you using on `$this->_dbConn`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not PHP related. I've looked into the table design and I noticed that the id column was unsigned and not checked for incredement.